# Set ajax response in data table

Tags: php, ajax, database

My data table file is like that I am getting result in AJAX response but I can not set that response in data table it is automatically set at top of page me already give class in div but I can not get proper result:

```
<?php
  include 'header.php';
  include 'footer.php';

  if(isset($_REQUEST['delete_id']))
  {
      $delete_id = $_REQUEST['delete_id'];
      $query = "DELETE contact, address, addressgroup FROM contact, address, addressgroup WHERE contact.contact_id = '$delete_id'  AND address.contact_id = '$delete_id' AND addressgroup.contact_id='$delete_id'";
      $query = mysql_query($query);
  }
?>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );

var myarray;
function getcon() {
  myarray = [];
  myarray.push($(".group_id").val());
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getcon.php",
      data: 'group_id=' + myarray.join(),
      success: function(data) {
          $('.group').html(data);
      }
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<div class="wrapper row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
  <?php include 'admin_leftside.php'; ?>
  <aside class="right-side">                
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>Contact List</h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Contact List</li>
    </ol>
    </section>
<section class="content">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-11">
    <div class="box box-primary">
      <div class="box-header"></div>
        <div class="box-body">
          <form method="post">

            <table id="example" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                   <td>
                     <select class="group_id" name="group_id[]" onchange="getcon();" multiple>
                       <option disabled selected>Select Group</option>
                       <?php
                          $select = "SELECT group_id,group_name
                                      FROM `group`";
                          $res1 = mysql_query($select);
                          while($group1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1))
                          {
                            echo '<option value='.$group1['group_id'].'>'.$group1['group_name'].'</option>';
                          }
                       ?>
                     </select>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Password</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                  </tr>
                   <tbody>
                      <tr>
                          <div class="group"></div>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
              </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</aside><!-- /.right-side -->
</div><!-- ./wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this line

```
$("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy();
var table= $('#example').DataTable({"order": []});
```

after

```
$('.group').html(data);
```

this will reload the data table

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=example - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Comment: it's give me alert like this @sujivasagam

Comment: try $("#example").dataTable().fnDestroy(); before initialise statement